# Donate disk and CPU capacity to a third party?

Tags: distributed-computing

Due to an impasse with one of our providers, we have come to have a non-trivial amount of CPU, and disk capacity that will stand unused for a number of months.

How can I find services that will, preferably over-utilize unused capacity?

Comment: Bitcoin/Litecoin mining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to a [list of distributed computing projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects) you could become involved in.